# template argument deduction/substitution failed variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a function that can take multiple arguments but i don't understand why I got this error :

```sh
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=gnu++17 -I include/headers/ -I include/headers/ecs/ -I include/headers/ecs/Components   -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/main.cpp:15:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘Entity::addComponent<Vector2D>(float, float)’
   15 |     auto &vector = entity.addComponent<Vector2D>(0.f, 0.f);
      |                                                          ^
In file included from include/headers/Ecs.hpp:11,
                 from src/main.cpp:9:
include/headers/ecs/Entity.hpp:41:56: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class ... Args> T& Entity::addComponent(Args&& ...)’
   41 |             template <typename T, typename... Args> T& addComponent(Args &&...args)
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
include/headers/ecs/Entity.hpp:41:56: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
make: *** [<builtin>: src/main.o] Error 1
```

main.cpp :

```cpp
int main(void) {
    World world;
    auto &entity = world.addEntity();
    auto &vector = entity.addComponent<Vector2D>(0.f, 0.f);
    return (0);
}
```

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args> T& addComponent(Args &&...args)
{
    if (!std::is_base_of<IComponent, T>::value)
        throw std::invalid_argument("'T' is not base of IComponent");
    m_components.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(args...));
    return (*m_components.end());
}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] please?

Comment: For compile-time constrains, consider using `static_assert` instead of run-time throwing.

Comment: Not what you're asking for, but I think you should be using `std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` there.

Comment: Replace `end()` by `back()` then the dereferenced type will be `Vector2D&` instead `unique_ptr<Vector2D>` which doesn't match to `Vector2D&`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on my code, I will modify my code. 
I have solved the problem, I forget to write Vector<float> in the main function.